# Pygame Drawing Rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to draw a rectangle on the screen. My code is below:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),
                    (self.width/2-20,self.height/2-20,40,40),
                    width=0)
```

Pygame keeps returning the error message:

> TypeError: rect() takes no keyword arguments

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried both. But it returned the same error message.

Comment: Instead of width=0 put only 0 i.e. pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0), [self.width/2-20,self.height/2-20,40,40], 0). See https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect  for how to use this function

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `pygame` documentation, `pygame.draw.rect` needs which screen to draw to, the color, a `Rect` object, and the width. You should have `pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(self.width/2-20, self.height/2-20, 40, 40), 0)` instead. (If you take a look at the [comment](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#comment_pygame_draw_rect) by Dave Burton on this function, you'll additionally see that you shouldn't put `width=0`.)

Comment: Consider accepting if it worked :) Its to show that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It ended up being my pygame version even though I thought I installed the latest.
I installed it using `conda install -c cogsci pygame`. This is wrong, since that version has not been updated in at least four years. Instead, install it using pip: `pip install pygame`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have all the ingredients? You need an init function an update function also for example. Try something like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

while True:

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen.fill(BLACK)


    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [100, 100, 400, 300])
    pygame.display.update()
```